# Unable to plot a sliced Data frame; KeyError on 'ColumnName'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to python and am trying to create a simple line plot from a data frame

[image: data frame]

and when trying to use the following command I receive the following error "KeyError: RegionName". From what I have seen this error means that the column name in my case doesn't exist which is obviously not the case.
Also note that this data frame has been created as a slice of another.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

region_data = pd.merge(q4, q5, on = 'AeId')

#refine the columns --> cut slack
region_data_refined = region_data.drop(['TimePeriodId_y', 'AeName', 'RgoCode','AeId', 'IsActive','RegionCode'], axis=1)

#get region totals
region_totals = region_data_refined.groupby(['BenefitCode', 'RegionName']).sum()

region_totals.drop('TimePeriodId_x', axis=1, inplace=True)

region_pct_26 = region_totals.iloc[6:12, :]
region_pct_26['Opp_Lives_pct'] = ((region_pct_26.Lives / region_pct_26.Lives.sum())*100).round(2)

region_pct_26.plot(x ='RegionName', y='Opp_Lives_pct', kind = 'line')
```

Comment: These are discreet, not continuous values. They should be plotted on a bar plot, not a line plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from when you use the `groupby()` function. `RegionName` becomes a lower level index. When trying to plot using `region_pct_26.plot()`, the column `RegionName` is no longer a "column". It's part of the dataframe's index.

```
>>> region_pct_26.unstack(level=0).plot(y='Opp_Lives_pct', kind = 'line')
```

If the issue persists, try

```
>>> region_pct_26.unstack(level=0).reset_index().plot(x='RegionName', y='Opp_Lives_pct', kind = 'line')
```

Comment: I reset RegionName as a column and it works now! Thank you!